# How much computing power does it take to decompress MP3?

Tags: performance, mp3

Assuming you are doing it on the CPU, not using dedicated hardware, how much computing power, in megaflops, does it take to decompress a moderate quality MP3 stream?

Comment: First mainstream software player was WinPlay3.  It required a 486DX running at 66 MHz, heavy at the time.  MIPS claims for that chip are rather broad (26 .. 54), I'd aim at ~35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a paper explaining some optimization details for an MP3 decoder application for a non-pc device:

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE-255.pdf

Still, the paper sheds some light on the issue by giving numeric measurements of instruction counts per second: The original implementation of the algorithm takes 330 Mips. After applying some optimizations, the number reduces to 110 Mips. So, it is a very modest number. A fraction of what CPUs are capable of today.

Your milage may vary depending on the instruction set you will use or requirements of your application. Also keep in mind that the implementation makes a big difference. As it is shown on the paper, missing a couple optimizations could slow down it thrice.